# How to append to variable from within another function in clojure?

Tags: clojure

The question doesn't really explain what I want to do but I couldn't think of anything else.

I have an empty map in the outer `let` function in a piece of code, and an integer array. 
I want to iterate through the integer array, perform a simple task, and keep appending the resulting map to the variables in the outer variables.

```
(let [a {}  ;outer variables
      b {}]
  (doseq [x [1 2 3]]
         (let [r (merge a {x (* x x)}) ;I want to append this to a
               s (merge b {x (+ x x)})] ;and this to b
           (println (str "--a--" r "--b--" s)))))
```

But as soon as I get out of `doseq`, my `a` and `b` vars are still empty. I get that the scope of a and b doesn't extend outside of doseq for it to persist any changes done from within and that they are immutable.

How do I calculate the values of a and b in such cases, please? I tried to extract the functionality of doseq into another function and calling let with:

```
(let [a (do-that-function)])
```

etc but even then I couldn't figure out a way to keep track of all the modifications within doseq loop to then send back as a whole.

Am I approaching this in a wrong way?

Thanks

---

**edit**

Really, what I'm trying to do is this:

```
(let [a (doseq [x [1 2 3]] {x (* x x)})]
  (println a))
```

but doseq returns nil so a is going to be nil :-s

Comment: As a pedantic point, there are no variables in clojure. Symbols are bound to values. The value does not change, and hence is not variable (but the symbol can, in a different context, bind to a different value). Things like atoms and refs can act like variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to think in terms of flows of data adding to existing data making new data, instead of changing past data. For your specific problem, where a data structure is being built, reduce is typically used:

```
(reduce (fn [result x] (assoc result x (* x x))) {} [1 2 3])
```

hehe, I just noticed that "reduce" might seem confusing given that it's building something, but the meaning is that a collection of things is "reduced" to one thing. In this case, we give reduce an empty map to begin with, which binds to result in the fn, and each successive mapping over the collection results in a new result, which we add to again with assoc.

You could also say:

```
(into {} (map (fn [x] [x (* x x)]) [1 2 3]))
```

In your question you wanted to make multiple things at once from a single collection. Here's one way to do that:

```
(reduce (fn [[a b] x] [(assoc a x (* x x)) (assoc b x (+ x x))]) [{} {}] [1 2 3])
```

Here we used destructuring syntax to refer to our two result structures - just make a picture of the data [with [vectors]]. Note that reduce is still only returning one thing - a vector in this case.

And, we could generalize that:

```
(defn xfn [n fs] 
  (reduce 
    (fn [results x] (map (fn [r f] (assoc r x (f x x))) results fs)) 
      (repeat (count fs) {}) (range n)))

=> (xfn 4 [* + -])
({3 9, 2 4, 1 1, 0 0} {3 6, 2 4, 1 2, 0 0} {3 0, 2 0, 1 0, 0 0})
```

The result is a list of maps. And if you wanted to take intermediate steps in the building of these results, you could change reduce to reductions. Generally, `map` for transforming collections, `reduce` for building a single result from a collection.

Answer (score 3):

All variables in clojure are immutable. If you need a mutable state you should use [atoms](http://clojure.org/atoms) or [refs](http://clojure.org/Refs).

But in your case you can simply switch from `doseq` to `for`:

```
(let [a (for [x [1 2 3]] {x (* x x)})]
  (println a))
```

Here is an example of solving your problem with atoms:

```
(let [a (atom {})
      b (atom {})]
  (doseq [x [1 2 3]]
    (swap! a assoc x (* x x))
    (swap! b assoc x (+ x x)))
  (println "a:" @a)
  (println "b:" @b))
```

But you should avoid using mutable state as far as possible:

```
(let [l [1 2 3]
      a (zipmap l (map * l l))
      b (zipmap l (map + l l))]
  (println "a:" a)
  (println "b:" b))
```

Comment: oh gee! `for` does the job! Thanks for the explanation too!